# UnrecoverableKeyException on trying to read key using alias from keystore

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am getting the following error on Line #4 of code below in IBM Websphere
Liberty Profile 16.0.0

```
InputStream keystoreStream = EncryptionUtility.class.getResourceAsStream(keyStoreLocation);         
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
keystore.load(keystoreStream, storePass.toCharArray());
Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, keyPass.toCharArray());
```

Which results in the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: com.ibm.crypto.provider.AESSecretKey
at com.sun.crypto.provider.KeyProtector.unseal(KeyProtector.java:358)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineGetKey(JceKeyStore.java:133)
at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:804)
at com.comdata.base.helper.EncryptionUtility.initSymmetricKey(EncryptionUtility.java:134)
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Is anything need to be configured for cryptography?

I poked through the code of keyProtector.java in JDK 7 and UnrecoverableKeyException is triggered by ClassNotFoundException 
com.ibm.crypto.provider.AESSecretKey

Do we need to install any feature via installUtility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas why this is happening? Is anything need to be configured for cryptography?

The class not being found (`com.ibm.crypto.provider.AESSecretKey`) is from the IBM JDK.

It looks like your keystore was created using the IBM JDK and thus has a key packaged in it that uses the `AESSecretKey` from the IBM JDK.

At runtime, your Liberty server is probably using a non-IBM JDK, which would not have this IBM JDK specific class in it.

> Do we need to install any feature via installUtility?

Nope.  The missing class should be provided by the JDK, as opposed to a Liberty feature.

Comment: great! after using ibm jdk initialization of crypto module is successful!